# Cookie[] getCookies()の配列要素数は、何と比例した数なのでしょうか

Tags: java, cookie

Cookie[] getCookies()の実行結果配列数が、1つの場合や2つの場合があり、その要素数は何の個数に紐づいているものなのかが分かりません。

分かる方がいましたら、ご教授をお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookieってどこから生まれたかと言うことでしょうかね。

Cookieは基本的に開発者が意識的に作成して、利用しています。
作成する方法は２つがあって、
１。サーバーサイドで作成し、ブラウザへのHTTPリスポンスのヘッダーに「作成してくれ」と明記する
ソース例：

> Cookie cookie = new Cookie("cookie_name","cookie_value");
>   response.addCookie(cookie);

２。ブラウザのほうで、Javascriptを利用して、作成する。
参考例：http://qiita.com/takanorip/items/4e23b803bb1393176636

以上の２つの方法でCookieを作成したら、リクエストごとに作成したCookie情報を持つようになります。
それに、Cookieごとにpathやdomainやexpireなどの属性もあるので、その辺は（２）の参考例をご参考いただければと思います。

ブラウザにどのようなCookieが存在するかはChromeブラウザの Developer Tools を利用して、確認することができますので、この記事をご参考ください。
http://www.buildinsider.net/web/chromedevtools/01

Comment: とても丁寧なご回答をありがとう御座いました。理解することが出来ました。

Answer (score 0):

「実行結果配列数＝クライアントから送られてきたCookieの数」のはずですが、そうではないケースがあったということでしょうか？

Comment: [クライアントから送られてきたCookieの数]が、何の数のことが分からない状態です。具体的には、何が増えると[クライアントから送られてきたCookieの数]が増えるのでしょうか？

Comment: これに対する回答は @kaku_kk さんが答えてくれている通りです。